# How to add RTC timer in linux kernel module

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to start task after hard specified time in my kernel module, I suspect that it should be done through rtc.h.

For example I need to send kick signal to my external watchdog every 50 mseconds.
Is there any example to demonstrate how to implement rtc timer in linux kernel module?

Comment: Signalling a watchdog shouldn't require an RTC. It should also be triggered from user space, rather than from kernel space. (The *trigger* should start in user space. It's possible that you'll need some kernel support, which can be implemented as a regular watchdog using the existing watchdog framework.)

Comment: OK, the watchdog is not good example. My main question - how to start rtc timer in kernel module. I need to run task after hard specified time.

Comment: That's actually also something which you almost certainly should be doing from user space instead. There are plenty of examples of how to register and implement an RTC driver in drivers/rtc, but I don't think there's a framework for accessing it from the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

My comments above may have been wrong. Apparently this *is* possible from kernel space.

There's a collection of functions in drivers/rtc/interface.c which will probably let you do what you want. 
They're rtc_initialize_alarm(), rtc_set_alarm(), ...

For things like a watchdog you'd just want to use regular relative-time timers (add_timer() and friends). You'd use rtc_set_alarm() for things like 'do this on 01/01/2014 at 01:13'.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot find i can not find any usage example how to properly initialize timer (delay alarm) with these functions